# loosing precision in division with DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I encounter strange DB2 behaviour. An example will illustrate it :

```
SELECT CAST(11458.5648 AS DECIMAL(30,10)) / CAST(120.1 AS DECIMAL(30,10)), 11458.5648 / 120.1 FROM MYTABLE FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

returns :

```
 1          | 2        
---------------------------
       95.4 | 95.4085328893
```

Of course, the good result is in column 2, but why DB2 does this awful error ?

If I cast to DECIMAL(20,10), the result is good too, but starting with DECIMAL(22,10), I loose 1 digit of precision in the result at each step ...

Any idea about it ?

thanks

Comment: I haven't tested this on DB2, but DB2's `DECIMAL` range should fully support `DECIMAL(30,10)`.  I tried your code on SQL Server and could not reproduce it.

Comment: Try instead `CAST(11458.5648 AS DECFLOAT) / CAST(120.1 AS DECFLOAT), 11458.5648 / 120.11`  . You will see the cause if you use `describe values CAST(11458.5648 AS DECIMAL(30,10)) / CAST(120.1 AS DECIMAL(30,10))`  , it may show type decimal with length 31,1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how decimal arithmetic is handled (for your platform & version of Db2)

For [Db2 LUW v11.5](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html)

> Two decimal operands If both operands are decimal, the operation is
> performed in decimal. The result of any decimal arithmetic operation
> is a decimal number with a precision and scale that are dependent on
> the operation and the precision and scale of the operands. If the
> operation is addition or subtraction and the operands do not have the
> same scale, the operation is performed with a temporary copy of one of
> the operands. The copy of the shorter operand is extended with
> trailing zeros so that its fractional part has the same number of
> digits as the longer operand.
>
> The result of a decimal operation cannot have a precision greater than
> 31. The result of decimal addition, subtraction, and multiplication is derived from a temporary result which can have a precision greater
> than 31. If the precision of the temporary result is not greater than
> 31, the final result is the same as the temporary result.
>
> Decimal arithmetic in SQL Use the formulas shown here to calculate the
> precision and scale of the result of decimal operations in SQL. The
> formulas use the following symbols:
> p Precision of the first operand.
> s Scale of the first operand.
> p' Precision of the second operand.
> s' Scale of the second operand.

[image]

Assuming the default mode, by casting the operands to decimal(30,10) your results has
p = 31
s = 31-30+10-10 ==> 1

moral of the story, don't artificially increase the precision and scale of your operands.